# Extract words from string before new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers

I recently asked the question how to extract words from string before number, to help me sort some data. This works perfectly until there is no number in front and only a new line.

This was done by codenewbie

```
import re

strings = '''
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test
'''

for s in strings.split('\n'):
    if s != '':
        print(re.findall('(.+?)\d',s)[0])
```

This gives

```
Hi my name is hazza 
Hi hazza 
hazza
```

Which is perfect but fails if a string has no number in front but a new line

```
import re

strings = '''
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test

hazza hazza test test test
'''

for s in strings.split('\n'):
    if s != '':
        print(re.findall('(.+?)\d',s)[0])
```

I need it to  give me

```
Hi my name is hazza 
Hi hazza 
hazza 
hazza hazza
```

I have tried

```
import re

strings = '''
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test

hazza hazza
test test test
'''

    while True:
            try:
                for s in strings.split('\n'):
                    if s != '':
                        print(re.findall('(.+?)\d',s)[0])
            except IndexError:
                print(s.split('/n'))
```

But not completely sure where to put the break in and if there is a better way

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:

I have these stings for example

```
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test

hazza hazza
test test test
```

The code done by codenewbie works fine for the first three strings but not the last.

I need the last to look like

```
Hi my name is hazza 
Hi hazza 
hazza 
hazza hazza
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no attempt to solve the literal question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use re.match() `[^\d]*` to match any non-digit characters:

```
import re

strings = '''
Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test

hazza hazza test test test
'''

for s in strings.splitlines():
    if s != '':
        print(re.match(r'[^\d]*',s)[0])
```

Prints:

```
Hi my name is hazza 
Hi hazza 
hazza 
hazza hazza test test test
```

---

EDIT: Based on the comments, the new version:

```
import re

strings = '''Hi my name is hazza 50 test test test

Hi hazza 60 test test test

hazza 50 test test test

hazza hazza
test test test
'''

for s in re.findall(r'(.*?)(?:\n\n|\n$)', strings, flags=re.S):
    print(re.match(r'(.*?)(?=\d|\n)', s)[0])
```

Prints:

```
Hi my name is hazza 
Hi hazza 
hazza 
hazza hazza
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't add this to the question to start with but could I use that if the test test test part was on a new line and then get it to remove that part?

Comment: @TheAmazingHAzza Can you edit your question and put it there? With correct formatting and expected output.

Comment: No, I need it to remove the line beneath to leave me with just hazza hazza but it also needs to take out everything after a number if a number is present

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time in helping me